# Sending an image array as JSON response using DRF

Tags: arrays, json, image, django-rest-framework

I want to send an image array in a JSON as follows:

```
{"id":1,"timeIntervel":4,"images":["http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/i1.jpg","http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/i2.jpg","http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/i3.jpg","http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/i4.jpg","http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/i5.jpg"]}
```

I tried this with a foreignkey to my model. But failed to get a response as above.

model.py

```
class slidesModel(models.Model):
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.images.name)

class slideImageArrayModel(models.Model):
    timeIntervel=models.IntegerField()
    images = models.ForeignKey(slidesModel, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

serializer.py

```
class slideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = slidesModel
        fields='__all__'

class slideImgArraySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = slideImageArrayModel
        fields='__all__'
        depth = 1
```

views.py

```
class slidesViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = slideImageArrayModel.objects.all()
        user = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=1) #it will always sends the first object
        serializer = slideImgArraySerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My existing output is something which needs some modification to achieve the actual output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "timeIntervel": 4,
    "images": {
        "id": 8,
        "images": "/images/b1.jpg"
    }
}
```

I'm testing this in localhost and it's not showing complete url. I've included MEDIA_ROOT url already in settings and urls.py

Comment: Shouldn't you define the `ForeignKey` in the *opposite* direction?

Comment: You mean in the slideImageArrayModel? It'll be giving same result right?

Comment: no, since a `ForeignKey` is a many-to-one relation, so multiple images can map to the same `slidesModel`, and a `slidesModel` can have zero, one, or multiple images.

Comment: Can you please give me an example or any reference link? I'm quite new to Django

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for your help. I've modified my code portion as you suggested. But, it's not exactly what I required.I'm not able to include more than one image in the images field. (You can see the updated code portions in my question with latest modifications)

Comment: Can somebody give me a hint on how to proceed on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Just add **localhost:8000** in frontend part.
**Like this code**

```
<img src={"http://localhost:8000"+ note.img} alt="" role={'button'} onClick={(e)=> window.open(e.target.src)}/>
```

That will solve your issue.

Comment: Please use answer posts neither for asking your own questions nor for advertising other of your posts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).